# adding additional acceptable input argument types via a decorator

Tags: python, decorator, python-decorators, type-hinting

How to add additional input parameter types via a decorator in Python and have the type hinting work properly. The example below is unhappy in the last line due to the input of a string. Ultimately I want to allow user-defined custom types and some defaults custom types via an ABC method and have the method react accordingly (method overloading?). This is a test of the concept. Any suggestions?

```
import functools

def str_is_ok_too(func):
    '''decorator to strips any input of type string'''
    @functools.wraps(func)
    def wrapper(arg):
        if isinstance(arg, str):
            print("input is a string")
            def alt_func(arg: str) -> None:
                print(f'"{arg}"')
            alt_func(arg)
        else:
            print("input is int or float")
            func(arg)
    return wrapper


@str_is_ok_too
def accept_int_or_float(arg: int | float) -> None:
    '''prints input of type int or float'''
    print(arg)


accept_int_or_float(1)
accept_int_or_float(1.3)
accept_int_or_float("5")  # unhappy
```

Comment: Why not use type hint of `Union[float, str]`?

Comment: You could just not use type hinting.

Comment: your IDE is unhappy? who cares... its not smart enough to figure out its type is overridden ... it should still let you call it as long as you arent running it via mpy or something

Comment: `functools.singledispatch` suits your need. See doc: https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html?highlight=singledispatch#functools.singledispatch

Answer (score 0):

consider using `functools.singledispatch`([doc](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html?highlight=singledispatch#functools.singledispatch)), or other libraries([multimethod](https://pypi.org/project/multimethod/)) to achieve function overwritten for different types(a.k.a generic function). In this way, you can easily extend the functionalities by registering new implementations with type hints.

BTW, my IDE(PyCharm) will not throw a warning when I pass a string as input of `fun` in `singledispatch` way.

```
from functools import singledispatch


@singledispatch
def fun(args):
    print(args)


@fun.register
def _(args: str):
    print(f'"{args}"')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    fun(1)
    fun(1.5)
    fun("6")
```

Comment: Since I was planning to use this for extending the allowable input arguments for a class method, `@singledispatchmethod` would be the appropriate decorator (I did not know about either option, so thank you), but by using `@singledispatchmethod`, the linter now is OK with all input parameters, e.g., tuple, not just with int, float, and string.